# Configurar Mysql Workbench no docker

Tags: mysql, docker

Quero configurar meu Workbench para que consiga se conectar com o mysql que está rodando no meu servidor docker, mas quando tento testar a conexão, sempre recebo o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Criei o container do meu Mysql usando docker-compose. Segue abaixo a configuração do meu docker-compose.yml:

```
php:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
  volumes:
    - ./teste:/var/www/html
  links: 
    - mysql  

mysql:
  image: mysql:latest
  volumes:
   - /var/lib/mysql
  environment:
   - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
   - MYSQL_DATABASE=docker

phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  links:
   - mysql
  ports:
   - 3306:80
  environment:
   MYSQL_USERNAME: root
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
   PMA_HOST: mysql
```

Estou usando windows 10 com a versão 13.07.1 do docker. Tanto o mysql workbench quanto o meu servidor estão rodando localmente.

Atualmente para mim acessar o meu projeto docker apenas digito localhost no meu navegador, e para acessar o phpmyadmin digito localhost:3306.

Comment: Disponibiliza uma porta no mysql tbm, e a porta que vc disponibilizar vc coloca no workbench tbm.
Dai certeza que vai funcionar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É preciso mapear a porta do docker mysql para o host. No seu caso ficaria dessa maneira o trecho do mysql:

```
mysql:
  image: mysql:latest
  volumes:
   - /var/lib/mysql
  environment:
   - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
   - MYSQL_DATABASE=docker
  ports:
   - 3306:3306
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, apenas faltava mapear a porta do mysql. Para funcionar também alterei a porta do phpmyadmin, para evitar conflito. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

```
docker run --name mysqldb -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql
```

Executando a imagem no shell, você precisa definir a porta(`-p 3306:3306`) da sua máquina que irá conectar com a porta do MySQL no seu Docker.

Exemplo: `3306:3306`, ou seja, quando eu acessar a porta 3306 da minha máquina eu estarei conectando com a porta 3306 do MySQL no meu Docker.

Esse link mostra a conexão sendo feita: https://imasters.com.br/data/utilizando-docker-com-mysql

Comment: Bem-vindo e parabéns pela resposta! Mas como a pergunta indica que é usado o docker-compose, utilize o mesmo na sua resposta. E também nas se esqueça de formatar códigos e evitar adicionar referências externas, pois elas podem ser alteradas ou até removidas.